# bash: colored output do not stop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, passwords

I'm writing a password validator and after all the tests I need to give an answer to the user if the password is valid or not.
If it is valid I will write the password in green color
If it is NOT valid I will write the password in red color
My problem is that the color does not stop, the rest of the output would be in color as well for example:
Your password is NOT valid!  *ffsdmkl !
Your password must contain a minimum of 10 characters, Your password must contain both alphabet and number*
--> from the beginning of the password until the end of the sentence it would be colored.
How can I fix it guys?

Thanks!!

```
green='\033[0;32m'
red='\033[0;31m'
if [[ $valid1 == true && $valid2 == true && $valid3 == false  ]]; then
   echo -e "Your password is valid! ${green} ${PASSWORD} ${clear}!"
else
   echo -e "Your password is NOT valid! ${red} ${PASSWORD} !"
   echo $RESULT
fi
```

Comment: Where do you clear the red colour in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the variable `clear` as well, and use it whenever the text should not be in color anymore. Because `clear` is also a Bash command, I would change the variable name to something else like `reset`:

```
green='\033[0;32m'
red='\033[0;31m'
reset='\e[0m'
if [[ $valid1 == true && $valid2 == true && $valid3 == false  ]]; then
   echo -e "Your password is valid! ${green}${PASSWORD} ${reset}!"
else
   echo -e "Your password is NOT valid! ${red}${PASSWORD} ${reset}!"
   echo $RESULT
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
green='\033[0;32m'
red='\033[0;31m'
reset='\u001b[0m'
if [[ $valid1 == true && $valid2 == true && $valid3 == false  ]]; then
   echo -e "Your password is valid! ${green} ${PASSWORD} ${reset}!"
else
   echo -e "Your password is NOT valid! ${red} ${PASSWORD} ${reset}!"
   echo $RESULT
fi
```